# IntelliJ cannot create a new project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have been using Eclipse for about a year and decied to try put IntelliJ instead however I am having trouble setting it up. I just want to create a simple Java application. So I start IntelliJ and press New Project. Then I choose Java on the left side and then in the Project SDK dropdown, I choose my Java JDK 1.8.0_91.  From here I do not know what to do. I can add some additional libraries; Groovy, Kotlin(Java) and Kotlin(Javascript) but it does not matter which options I use because I cannot continue.[image: IntelliJ]

Comment: just go groovy and get going.

Comment: Doesn't work. If I choose Groovy, it sais Libary is not specified and I have to find the location of a Groovy distribution.

Comment: Just pick empty project, then

Comment: Doesn't work either, nothing happends there. Just a spinning loading thing that spins forever, cannot continue.

Comment: then find location of groovy distribution. or re install.